# No Resource found error When trying to Run James Montemagno Navigation Template for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I downloaded `XamAndroidTemplateVSIX.vsix` and it has been added to Visual Studio fine. The problem is when I try to build it says `No Resource found that matches the given name:attr'colorPrimary'`.

It's like it's not recognizing any resources from the `styles.xml` folder even tho the folder is in the values folder.

My SDK and Build Tools are all up to date. API 23.

What could be causing this error please?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Android support libraries are outdated. Open the NuGet package manger and update them to the latest version and your app will compile without any problems.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but updated them even before posting this question and I am still getting the same error

Comment: have you performed a clean rebuild after updating?

Comment: Yeah, eventually even the basic android apps stopped compiling so I'm doing reinstall of everything. SDK. Xamarin. Visual studio. Formatted Windows

Comment: Ok. Tell me if it's working after you've done your stuff ;)